# How do I get jenkins JJB to use jenkins environment vars? particularly for webhooks

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, gitlab, jenkins-job-builder

We're on jenkins 2.108 and JJB 2.0.3

We've got a manually created job that gets activated by a git webhook. Part of that job gets info like the repo name and does stuff with it. Like this

```
./build_rpm.sh -C \${gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit}
```

What the script does isn't important, just that it's run as part of the job and it gets the commit from the webhook.

Now I'm trying to replicate this job in JJB, but having no luck, so far I've tried

```
       echo {env.gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit} "WOOO"
   echo ${env.gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit} "WOOO"
   echo ${gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit} "WOOO"
   echo \${env.gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit} "WOOO"

   echo {{env.gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit}} "WOOO"
   echo ${{env.gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit}} "WOOO"
```

The first 4 all cause JJB to throw a wobbler with "Key error env" or similar, the last 2 allow JJB to proceed, but the task literally echos "{env.gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit}" it doesn't see it as a variable.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out, it's

```
echo ${{gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit}} "WOOO"
```